# override static instancetype method in swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift, static-methods, instancetype

I want to use this objective-C library in my swift code:

https://github.com/Alex601t/Catamaran

According to instruction I need to subclass a defined class and override method which declared as:

```
+ (instancetype)OAuth
```

How to implement it? I try to write the following:

```
class func OAuth() -> Self { ... }
```

It is not compiled and shows error that I need to add `override`. If I fix it - it writes that `OAuth()` is replaced by `init()`. If I try to fix it then I get other errors.

Could you explain how to fix that correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
   override init() {
       // use here your custom constructor
       self.initWithBaseUrl ... // etc.
   }
```